# Is there a way to force delete branch from aws codecommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

When you first create repository on aws codecommit through their API, that repository does not have any branches. Later when you create branch (e.g. master) it is the default one now and there is no way to delete it.

Does anyone know if there is some king of a workaround that will allow deleting of default branch on codecommit through API?

Answer (score 0):

CodeCommit supports updating default branch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateDefaultBranch.html, deleting non -default branch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteBranch.html.  Can you clarify the use case a little bit so that  we can understand why you need to delete the default branch directly?

Comment: This is the use case. I have a module that can have multiple versions and they can be published to my module storage as well as to s3 and codecommit. Semantic versions (1.0.0, 1.1.1, etc) are stored on module storage and on aws s3, but master version is stored on module storage and codecommit (since it is master version and is not stamped so it can be changed). I want to be able to delete master version from my module storage and from codecommit but want codecommit repo to exist even though it does not have any versions.